# Playing Video file from SD card

Tags: android

I m trying to play a video from SD card, I hav PUSH-ed a video into mnt/sdcard folder from DDMS view in eclipse.But the emulator screen shows blank without any error. Pls help.

```
public class Video extends Activity {
private MediaController mc;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    videoPlayer("mnt/sdcard","bikekid",true);
}


public void videoPlayer(String path, String fileName, boolean autoplay){
    //get current window information, and set format, set it up differently, if you need some special effects
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    //the VideoView will hold the video
    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    //MediaController is the ui control howering above the video (just like in the default youtube player).
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    //assing a video file to the video holder
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path+"/"+fileName));
    //get focus, before playing the video.
    videoHolder.requestFocus();
    if(autoplay){
        videoHolder.start();
    }

 }

}/// end class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.getAbsolutePath()
```

instead of `"mnt/sdcard"`

Edit:

use this

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"bikekid");
Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(fie);
videoHolder.setVideoURI(mUri);
```

Comment: the sdcard folder can be different. So getting it programmatically is better. And your Uri is not of the type file:/// . So use the edited code

Comment: are you sure your file name is bikekid without any extension, like avi or mp4 ? check what is the value of file.exists()